# R Cannot be resolved to a variable.

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I am trying to run an simple android project from  a tutorial, However I am receiving the popular "R cannot be resolved to a variable" error. I have checked my gen folder and the R.id file is not there. This is the list of things I have tried so far:

1. have done a clean build several billion times.
2. fixed the project properties
3. There are no errors in my .xml files and they do not contain uppercase letters etc.
4. The package name in the source and manifest are exactly the same.
5. Have installed the latest SDK updates + restarted eclipse.
6. have deleted the gen file and done another clean build.

There is only an error in the source files, according to eclipse.

Here is a themes.xml file that may be causing a problem:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@+color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles --> 
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
           parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs text styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabText"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Apologies in advance if this sounds familiar, but I have tried everything I have seen from previous posts.

Happy to provide more details if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eclipse probably "helped" the source file that won't compile by adding an import that you didn't want... look at the top of it to see.

Comment: Check if you have the 32 bit JDK installed on your system, also check for updates to Eclipse Plugins.

Answer (score 0):

`Theme.Holo` and `Widget.Holo.ActionBar` requires API Level 11
`TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title` and `Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText` requires API Level 13

Check your `android:minSdkVersion`. If it is less than 13 than you can't build your project(or you have to duplicate your styles for different API Levels, using different api level folders under res). eclipse shows this kind of errors.

And also your Android Project Build Target must be at least API Level 13.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The minSDKVersion set to 14 in the manifest. The build target is set to android 4.3 (API 18).